# Java replaceAll() to pull numbers and periods

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have a line of output similar to "Spec-Version: 11.3.0". I'm struggling to pull only the version out, with periods, using replaceAll(). Right now I have something like this:

```
version = line.replaceAll("[\\D+\\.]" , "");
```

With this I'm getting a version of:

```
1130
```

No matter what combination of syntax I use I'm either losing the periods or pulling the entire line.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would store the version number  in the first group. Replace the whole string with the first group.

```
:\s*(.*$)
```

Your java string would be `":\\s*(.*$)"`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eU5lU1)

Comment: I agree that this is a perfect use case for capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing there is removing everything that is either a period, or is not a number (which includes periods).

Try `"[^\\d\\.]"`

Answer (score 0):

Your replace all is getting rid of anything not a digit or a period.

`version = line.replaceAll("[^\\.\\d]" , "");`

should replace anything not a digit and not a period

Answer (score 0):

```
/[^\d.]/g
```

Replaces anything that isn't a digit or ".".

[Here is a demo at Regexr](http://regexr.com/391qp)

Comment: you do not need the `|` in a character set. The `[]` already symbolizes a choice between the interior characters

Comment: Not quite sure why I was downvoted for supplying a working solution.

Comment: That's not valid Java.

Answer (score 0):

so many answers try this pattern to MATCH your request
`([\d.]+)$`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zJ7fJ2)

for a replace version use this pattern
`^.*?(?=[\d.]+$)`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oP6mV5)

Comment: if that pattern is used in `replaceAll` it will ONLY erase the numbers and periods.

Comment: use it with match not with replaceAll!

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you should clarify that this pattern cannot just be plugged in to the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, this is a perfect use case for a capture group. In java you can write the following:

```
String regex = ".*Spec-Version: ([\\d\\.]+).*";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("as asdgf sdf as Spec-Version: 12.3.1 asda sd]");

if (matcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println("Match found");
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

You will need to try the match on each line of text. I recommend this instead of `replaceAll` because it will most certainly be more flexible in the future. In fact, you will be able to match strings like:

```
pattern
  .matcher("124442 1 2.23.4.12 as asdgf sdf as Spec-Version: 12.3.1 asda sd] 12.12314.15421");
```

while in the case above, `replaceAll` will give '12444212.23.4.1212.3.112.12314.15421', which is not what you want.